# WordPress headers problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a CSS sprite from my WordPress thumbnail. There are 9 thumbnails and everything works fine. But when I include the function using `add_action('publish_post','make_sprite');` I get an error. I get the error when I try to publish a post.

The error is:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/softsail/public_html/wp-content/themes/ss3/includes/imgtest.php:41) in /home/softsail/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Faux answer]. But you can always flag your question and have it moved to [WP.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) instead for a more WP-specific advise. Not enough context in your question.

Your [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) function needs to send some [`header()`](http://php.net/header). This fails if you already made some output. That's what [headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers%20already%20sent) says and which appearantly is the case here. So, you cannot use it in a template for example.

If it returns any output (did not bother to read WP docs), then a common workaround is:

```
<?php
 $later_html = add_action("..");
```

And then print the results when you actually need them:

```
<template>
<?php print $later_html; ?>
...
```

Anyway, **just call it *earlier***. If you don't actually need the header output (check `pluggable.php on line 897`), then you can also just suppress it:

```
@( add_action('publish_post','make_sprite') );
```

Likely not the better option in this case.